# What is meant by 'overlap in your experience'?

Tags: meaning

Recently I had a conversation with an employer. I am in IT field. After seeing my works he said 'I'm seeing a lot of overlap in experience'. I am not sure what does he meant by this. Can anyone explain me what he is intending to say?

Comment: Perhaps he meant that you've listed a large number of areas where you have experience, but he thinks that actually you've mostly been doing the same type of thing, so your experience isn't as "broad" as might appear at first sight. If you didn't understand, you should have asked at the time. We can only guess.

Comment: That [s]he said the phrase "overlap in experience" is a nicer way of saying you're not experienced enough. That [s]he said "a lot" means that YOU MUST STAY AWAY from that company. They are the ones who expect you to read their minds, and even worse, "tell them what they have dreamed about last night because they can't remember, then interpret it." If something happens uneventfully, you will be blamed for not having foreseen and done something to prevent it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An overlap in experience would mean a lot of similarity between experience in one case and another; the set of expertise covered in each has a lot in common.

Unfortunately what isn't clear from your answer is what experience he was comparing with what.

It could mean between each of your projects and hence that you've done a lot of the same thing rather than having a more diverse overall experience in your career so far.

It could mean an overlap with what they already have in their team (both good and bad, you won't bring as much new, but you'll have an immediate understanding).

It could mean an overlap with the experience they're looking for in an ideal candidate, which would obviously be a good thing.

Sadly, I don't have enough to judge between those possibilities in your question.